# Converting a nested hash into a flat hash

Tags: ruby, hash

This question is the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404769).

Given a nested hash like

```
{
    :a => {
       :b => {:c => 1, :d => 2},
       :e => 3,
    },
    :f => 4,
}
```

what is the best way to convert it into a flat hash like

```
{
    [:a, :b, :c] => 1,
    [:a, :b, :d] => 2,
    [:a, :e] => 3,
    [:f] => 4,
}
```

Comment: So you want an array of keys in order that lead to a value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another way:

```
def flat_hash(h,f=[],g={})
  return g.update({ f=>h }) unless h.is_a? Hash
  h.each { |k,r| flat_hash(r,f+[k],g) }
  g
end

h = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1,
                      :d => 2 },
              :e => 3 },
      :f => 4 }

flat_hash(h) #=> {[:a, :b, :c]=>1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :e]=>3, [:f]=>4}
```

Comment: I know Ruby doesn't necessarily support TCO out of the box, but if you didn't return `g` here, would this be tail-call optimized?

Comment: I've heard the term "tail-call optimized" but I have no idea what it means. Perhaps a computer scientist can answer your question.

Comment: You can't optimize the tail call here IMO since you have a cascaded recursion.

Answer (score 16):

Very similar to Adiel Mittmann's solution

```
def flat_hash(h, k = [])
  new_hash = {}
  h.each_pair do |key, val|
    if val.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash.merge!(flat_hash(val, k + [key]))
    else
      new_hash[k + [key]] = val
    end
  end
  new_hash
end
```

**Edit:** Refactored for elegance. Should be almost as fast.

```
def flat_hash(hash, k = [])
  return {k => hash} unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.inject({}){ |h, v| h.merge! flat_hash(v[-1], k + [v[0]]) }
end
```

Comment: This one ran the fastest. Thanks.

Comment: @sawa: Just a tip for the future: If you want a fast solution, mention this in the question next time. Usually the main criterion in dynamic languages like Python or Ruby is elegancy and conciseness. If you specifically ask for performance as well, you could get much better suited answers :)

Comment: @sawa: refactored for elegance.

Comment: @Kyle One thing that was good about your earlier code was that it can be redefined as a method on `Hash`. The rewritten one cannot.

Comment: @Niklas, perhaps, but most Ruby-readers know sawa is a speed-freak.

Answer (score 8):

My attempt:

```
def flatten_hash(h)
  return { [] => h } unless h.is_a?(Hash)
  Hash[h.map { |a,v1| flatten_hash(v1).map { |b,v2| [[a] + b, v2] } }.flatten(1)]
end
```

Sorry for the bad variables names, had to fit it in one line.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an attempt to give you the *best* way to do it, but it is a way :P

```
def flatten(hash)
  return {[] => hash} if !hash.is_a?(Hash)
  map = {}
  hash.each_pair do |key1, value1|
    flatten(value1).each_pair do |key2, value2|
      map[[key1] + key2] = value2
    end
  end
  return map
end
```

It works for your example, producing this result:

```
{[:a, :b, :c]=>1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :e]=>3, [:f]=>4}
```

It may not produce the result you expect if there are empty hashes.

Answer (score 3):

A functional approach (see the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12270255/revisions) for an alternative implementations):

```
def recursive_flatten(hash)
  hash.flat_map do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      recursive_flatten(value).map { |ks, v| [[key] + ks, v] } 
    else
      [[[key], value]]
    end
  end.to_h
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Array support / readable names / no update for speed / stringified results keys

```
def flat_hash(input, base = nil, all = {})
  if input.is_a?(Array)
    input = input.each_with_index.to_a.each(&:reverse!)
  end

  if input.is_a?(Hash) || input.is_a?(Array)
    input.each do |k, v|
      flat_hash(v, base ? "#{base}.#{k}" : k, all)
    end
  else
    all[base] = input
  end

  all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @cary-swoveland way, but in Hash class :

```
class Hash
  def deep_flatten(previous_key=[])
    flat_hash = {}
    self.each do |key, value|
      next_key = previous_key+[key]
      flat_hash.update(value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.deep_flatten(next_key) : {next_key=>value})
    end
    return flat_hash
  end
end

h = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :d => 2 }, :e => 3 }, :f => 4 }

h.deep_flatten #=> {[:a, :b, :c]=>1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :e]=>3, [:f]=>4}
```

Answer (score 1):

A declarative solution using [DeepEnumerable](https://github.com/dgopstein/deep_enumerable/):

```
require 'deep_enumerable'

h = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1, :d => 2 }, :e => 3 }, :f => 4 }
```

---

```
h.deep_each.map do |k, v|
  [DeepEnumerable.deep_key_to_array(k), v]
end.to_h
```

or, for those who prefer point-free style

```
h.deep_each.to_h.shallow_map_keys(&DeepEnumerable.method(:deep_key_to_array))
```