# What is the most efficient way to collect arrays of nested hash keys that access the leaf-nodes?

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, nested, key

I have a nested hash and would like a single array, where each element is an array of keys which represents a path through a nested hash to the non-hashes (leaf-nodes).

For example, given the input:

```
x = Hash.new
x["a"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"]["c"] = "one"
x["a"]["b"]["d"] = "two"
x["a"]["e"] = "three"
x["f"] = Hash.new
x["f"]["g"] = "four"
```

I would like the output:

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"], ["a", "e"], ["f", "g"]]
```

The code below works using two recursive methods: one to generate a nested array, and the other to un-nest it !.

My Ruby intuition tells me there must be a much more efficient and elegant way of achieving this.  Can anyone suggest a 'golf' solution, or a perfectly Ruby Way solution?

```
def collect_key_paths(object, path=[])
  result = nil
  if object.is_a?(Hash)
    path_for_current_hash = object.map do |key, value|
      incremented_path = [path, key].flatten
      collect_key_paths(value, incremented_path)
    end
    result = path_for_current_hash
  else
    result = path
  end
  result
end

def smoothe(array, store=[])
  if array.none? { |element| element.is_a?(Array) }
    store << array
  else
    array.each do |element|
      store = smoothe(element, store)
    end
  end
  store
end


x = Hash.new
x["a"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"]["c"] = "one"
x["a"]["b"]["d"] = "two"
x["a"]["e"] = "three"
x["f"] = Hash.new
x["f"]["g"] = "four"

nested_key_paths = collect_key_paths(x)
puts "RESULT:#{smoothe(nested_key_paths)}"
```

The result of this code, running version 1.9.2 is:

```
RESULT:[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"], ["a", "e"], ["f", "g"]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a nested hash into a flat hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash)

Comment: You can first get the hash given in the duplicate question that I gave, and then take out the `keys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the 'best' way, but you can prevent having to loop over it twice to 'smoothe' the result:

```
def collect_key_paths(hash, path = [])
  items = []
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash) 
      items.push(*collect_key_paths(v, path + [k]))
    else
      items << (path + [k])
    end
  end
  items
end

p collect_key_paths(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hash
  def collect_key_paths(path=[])
    self.each.with_object([]) do |(k, v), a|
      if v.kind_of?(Hash)
        a.push(*v.collect_key_paths(path + [k]))
      else
        a << path + [k]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, following your example :

```
x = Hash.new
x["a"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"] = Hash.new
x["a"]["b"]["c"] = "one"
x["a"]["b"]["d"] = "two"
x["a"]["e"] = "three"
x["f"] = Hash.new
x["f"]["g"] = "four"

puts x.collect_key_paths.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation:

```
def collect_key_paths(hash)
  paths = []
  hash.each do |k, v|
    paths.concat( 
      Hash === v ? 
        collect_key_paths(v).map{ |path| [k, *path]} : 
        [k] 
    )
  end
  paths
end
```