# How to convert deep hash to array of keys

Tags: ruby

I want to programmatically convert this:

```
{
"a"=>
  {"1"=>
    {"A"=>
      {"Standard"=>"true"}
    }
  },
"b"=>
  {"1"=>
    {"A"=>
      {"Standard"=>"true"}
    }
  }
}
```

to an array like this:

```
['a/1/A/Standard', 'b/1/A/Standard']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of my other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash/9648410#9648410) - adapted for your situation. See the link for a more verbose solution to `flat_hash`

```
def flat_hash(hash, k = "")
  return {k => hash} unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.inject({}){ |h, v| h.merge! flat_hash(v[-1], k + '/' + v[0]) }
end

example = {...} # your example hash
foo = flat_hash(example).keys
=> ["/a/1/A/Standard", "/b/1/A/Standard"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def extract_keys(hash)
  return [] unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.each_pair.map {|key, value| [key, extract_keys(value)].join('/') }
end
extract_keys(hash)
=> ["a/1/A/Standard", "b/1/A/Standard"]
```

Comment: The block from map can be simplified to '[key, extract_keys(value)].join('/')'

Comment: Nice!  I didn't think about join traversing the array within the array.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [flatten](http://www.samlown.com/en/recursive_lambdas_and_how_to_completely_flatten_a_hash_in_ruby) lambda definition.

```
h = {
"a"=>
  {"1"=>
    {"A"=>
      {"Standard"=>"true"}
     }
  },
"b"=>
  {"1"=>
     {"A"=>
       {"Standard"=>"true"}
     }
  }
}

a = []

flatten =
  lambda {|r|
    (recurse = lambda {|v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        v.to_a.map{|v| recurse.call(v)}.flatten
      elsif v.is_a?(Array)
        v.flatten.map{|v| recurse.call(v)}
      else
        v.to_s
      end
    }).call(r)
  }

h.each do |k,v|
  a << k + "/" + flatten.call(v).join("/")
end
```

Output:

```
 ["a/1/A/Standard/true", "b/1/A/Standard/true"]
```