# Classic hash to dot-notation hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.0

Is there a simple way in Ruby 2/Rails 3 to transform this:

```
{a: {b: {"1" => 1, "2" => 2}, d: "Something"}, b: {c: 1}}
```

into this:

```
{"a.b.1" => 1, "a.b.2" => 2, "a.d" => "Something", "b.c" => 1}
```

I'm not talking about this precise hash but transform any hash into a dot-notation hash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a nested hash into a flat hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash). Not exactly the same, but can be applied with trivial change.

Comment: Yes it can, by joining the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the cleanest solution I could come up with right now:

```
def dot_it(object, prefix = nil)
  if object.is_a? Hash
    object.map do |key, value|
      if prefix
        dot_it value, "#{prefix}.#{key}"
      else
        dot_it value, "#{key}"
      end
    end.reduce(&:merge)
  else
    {prefix => object}
  end
end
```

Test:

```
input = {a: {b: {"1" => 1, "2" => 2}, d: "Something"}, b: {c: 1}}

p dot_it input
```

Output:

```
{"a.b.1"=>1, "a.b.2"=>2, "a.d"=>"Something", "b.c"=>1}
```