# ruby iterate through hash

Tags: ruby, algorithm, trie

I have a hash of hashes. This hash has a dictionary. I need to find all matches in it which have the same root. For example, I have:

```
#<Trie:0x00000001bf9a40 @root={
  "m"=>{"a"=>{"x"=>{
    :end=>true,
    "i"=>{"m"=>{
      :end=>true,
      "i"=>{"m"=>{"l"=>{"i"=>{"a"=>{"n"=>{:end=>true}}}}}}
    }},
    "w"=>{"e"=>{"l"=>{"l"=>{:end=>true}}}}
  }}}
}>
```

and words `"max"`, `"maxim"`, `"maximilian"`, `"maxwell"`. How do I get all words in this hash by the root? For example

```
t = Trie.new
t.add( .....# now we added words
t.find('max')
#result all words which begins from 'max'
t.find('maxim')
#result all words which begins from 'maxim' => maxim, maximilian
```

Comment: Not got time for a full answer, but here's a clue for resolving what remains after finding a prefix: `remaining = @root["m"]["a"]["x"]`. Your find method will need to discover that programmatically of course . . . this is an exercise in recursive methods - you'll need two, one to find, other to expand remaining

Comment: first i have. I can find string which i need. There is a problem in the second recursive method to find other matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my `find` method is very similar to @sawa's.  (I believe @sawa is the person who first taught me to use `inject` with `&:[]` in cases this like this, so that's fitting.)

Given:

```
class Trie
  def initialize(root)
    @root = root # Just a shortcut to use your data and focus on your question
  end

  # Recurses through Hash `h` to find all words starting with `s`
  def words(h, s, a=[])
    h.each do |k, v|
      if k == :end
        a << s
      else
        words(v, s+k, a)
      end
    end

    a
  end

  private :words

  def find(start)
    words(start.chars.inject(@root, &:[]), start) rescue []
  end
end

t = Trie.new({"m"=>{"a"=>{"x"=>{:end=>true,
                              "i"=>{"m"=>{:end=>true,
                                         "i"=>{"m"=>{"l"=>{"i"=>{"a"=>{"n"=>{:end=>true}}}}}}}},
                              "w"=>{"e"=>{"l"=>{"l"=>{:end=>true}}}}}}}})
```

You can do:

```
t.find('max')
# => ["max", "maxim", "maximimlian", "maxwell"]
t.find('maxi')
# => ["maxim", "maximimlian"]
t.find('maximi')
# => ["maximimlian"]
t.find('maxw')
# => ["maxwell"]
t.find('x')                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# => []
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the `inject` statement.

Comment: @bsd Sure. It's documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject). In this case it consecutively calls `[]` on the result of the previous call (starting with `@root` initially) using the letters from `start`.  It's an easy programmatic way of going from `'max'` to `@root['m']['a']['x']`. Someone (I'm pretty sure it was @sawa) used `inject` like this in another answer a couple months ago, and I committed it to memory because I find this usage quite elegant and initially non-obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. It just takes care of the prefix.

```
class Trie
  def find prefix
    expand(prefix, prefix.each_char.inject(@root, &:[])) rescue []
  end
  def expand prefix, affix
    #TODO
  end
end
```

Given `t.find("maxi")`, the implemented part `prefix.each_char.inject(@root, &:[])` returns:

```
{"m" => {
  :end => true,
  "i"  => {"m" => {"l" => {"i" => {"a" => {"n" => {:end => true}}}}}}
}}
```

and passes it and the prefix `"maxi"` to `Trie#expand`. Then, you need to expand that hash and combine it with the prefix. For that part, you may want to refer to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash).

Comment: Thank you both very much. I got working solution with sawa`s answer, but next gives me more advance. Great work

Comment: No problem. Darshan Computing's answer is a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt

```
# Returns all the possible matching suffixes for the `given` string.
# trie is a map of map of .. strings delimitted by :end
# cur_word is a scratch pad for storing characters from prev level. 
# Pass empty string for cur_word or create a wrapper around this function.
def all_suffix(trie, given, cur_word)
   #Suffixes found in the current iteration
   suffixes = []


   #The current node (character at which we want the Hash)
   at = given[0] 

   cur_word << (at || '')

   cur_trie = trie[at] || trie[cur_word[-1]] || {}

   #When we are at the end of the string, given.length <= 1 and we must print out all suffixes
   cur_trie.each do |next_str, next_trie|

     if next_str == :end
       #Only if we reached the end of the `given` string
       suffixes << cur_word if given.length <= 1
     else
       #Delete the first character and continue iteration
       other_suffixes = all_suffix({ next_str => next_trie },
                              given[1..-1] || '',
                              cur_word + (given.length > 1 ? '' : next_str))

       suffixes << other_suffixes.flatten if other_suffixes.size > 0 
     end
   end
   suffixes.flatten
end 

trie = {
  "m"=>{"a"=>{"x"=>{
    :end=>true,
    "i"=>{"m"=>{
      :end=>true,
      "i"=>{"m"=>{"l"=>{"i"=>{"a"=>{"n"=>{:end=>true}}}}}}
    }},
    "w"=>{"e"=>{"l"=>{"l"=>{:end=>true}}}}
  }}}
}
```

> p all_suffix(trie, "max", "")

```
["max", "maxim", "maximimlian", "maxwell"]
```

> p all_suffix(trie, "maxi", "")

```
["maxim", "maximimlian"]
```