# Given 2 hashes, how can I determine that the entirety of one hash exists within the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Given a reference hash, how can I determine that the entirety of another hash exists within the reference hash, beginning at the root level? The reference hash may have additional data, which should be ignored.

For example, `hash_to_check_1` exists within the `reference_hash`, so the check would return `true`.

```
# reference_hash
{
  a: {
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: {
      e: 5,
      f: 6
    }
    g: 7
  }
}

# hash to check
{
  a: {
    d: {
      e: 5,
    }
    g: 7
  }
}
```

But, the following would all return `false`, either because of different integer values, added keys, changed keys.

```
# hash to check
{
  new_key: {
    a: {
      d: {
        e: 5,
      }
      g: 7
    }
  }
}

# hash to check
{
  a: {
    d: {
      e: 5,
    }
    g: 7
  }
  z: 26
}

# hash to check
{
  a: {
    d: {
      e: 55,
    }
    g: 7
  }
}

# hash to check
{
  a: {
    h: {
      e: 5,
    }
    g: 7
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are not valid hashes.

Comment: It would help if you could add comments to the hashes explaining why each one should fail the check.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't tried anything and want us to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to "[Converting a nested hash into a flat hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash)". Using one of the answers given to that question, hashes can be converted into flat hashes.

For example, given, instead of what you claim are "hashes" (but are actually not even Ruby objects), the following real hashes:

```
reference_hash = 
{
  a: {
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: {
      e: 5,
      f: 6
    },
    g: 7
  }
}

hash_to_check =
{
  a: {
    d: {
      e: 5,
    },
    g: 7
  }
}
```

and using Cary's answer to the linked question:

```
def flat_hash(h,f=[],g={})
  return g.update({ f=>h }) unless h.is_a? Hash
  h.each { |k,r| flat_hash(r,f+[k],g) }
  g
end
```

you can get the flattened hashes:

```
h1 = flat_hash(reference_hash) #=> {
#  [:a, :b]     => 2,
#  [:a, :c]     => 3,
#  [:a, :d, :e] => 5,
#  [:a, :d, :f] => 6,
#  [:a, :g]     => 7
#}
h2 = flat_hash(hash_to_check) #=> {
# {[:a, :d, :e] => 5, [:a, :g]     => 7}
```

By doing:

```
h1.merge(h2) == h1 #=> true
```

you can tell that `hash_to_check` is included in `reference_hash`.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function can check this rather nicely:

```
def matches(x, y)
  return true if x == y
  return false unless x.is_a?(Hash) && y.is_a?(Hash)
  x.all? do |key, value|
    y.has_key?(key) && matches(x[key], y[key])
  end
end

reference = {a: 0, b: {x: 0, y: 1}}
matches(reference, {a: 0, b: {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2}, c: 'qqq'}) # true
matches(reference, {b: {x: 0, y: 1}}) # false
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has no built-in support for operations on deeply nested hashes. But you can extend the Hash class to recursively check if it includes another hash.

For each key we first check whether it's included and then wether its value is either included in (if it's a hash) or equal to (if it's anything else) the reference value. Since it's recursive, we don't need to bother about anymore levels of nesting.

```
class Hash
  def deep_include?(other)
    other.map do |key, value|
      include?(key) && 
      if fetch(key).respond_to?(:deep_include?)
        fetch(key).deep_include?(value)
      else
        fetch(key) == value
      end
    end.reduce(:&)
  end
end

hash = {a: {b: 2, c: 3, d: {e: 5, f: 6}, g: 7}}
hash.deep_include?(a: {d: {e: 5}, g: 7})
# => true
hash.deep_include?(new_key: {a: {d: {e: 5}, g: 7}})
# => false
hash.deep_include?(a: {d: {e: 5}, g: 7}, z: 26)
# => false
hash.deep_include?(a: {d: {e: 55}, g: 7})
# => false
hash.deep_include?(a: {h: {e: 5}, g: 7})
# => false
```

This code should be fairly robust, however, I only tested it against your examples.