# Ruby JSON node select, view & value change

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to select a node from a JSON parsed file and display the node/key hierarchy by using dots to separate the nodes.

```
json_hash =
{
    "Samples": {
        "Locations": {
            "Presets": "c:\\Presets\\Inst",
            "Samples": "c:\\Samples\\seperates\\round_robin"
        },
        "Format": {
            "Type": "AIFF",
            "Samplerate": 48,
            "Bitrate": 24
        },
        "Groupings": {
            "Type": "dynamic",
            "Sets": {
                "Keyswitch": "enabled",
                "Mods": "Enabled"
            }
        },
        "Ranges": {
            "Keys": {
                "LowKey": 30,
                "HighKey": 80,
                "LowVel": 0,
                "MidVel": 53,
                "HighVel": 127
            }
        },
        "Dynamics": {
            "DN": {
                "MultiRange": "enabled",
                "Range": [
                    "0-36",
                    "37-80"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Modulation": {
        "Pitch": true,
        "Range": []
    },
    "Encoded": false,
    "test": "test_one"
}
```

My idea is to output something like this;

```
Samples.Locations.Presets => c:\Presets\Inst
Samples.Locations.Samples => c:\Samples\seperates\round_robin
```

I managed to get this;

```
Presets. => c:\Presets\Inst 
Presets.Samples. => c:\Samples\seperates\round_robin
```

Using this code:

```
def node_tree(hash)
  kl = ''
  hash.each do |k, v|
    kl << "#{k}."
    if v.kind_of?(Hash)
      node_tree(v)
    else
      print "#{kl} => "
      print "#{Array(v).join(', ')}\n"
    end
  end
end

node_tree(json_hash)
```

It would be great if I could get the full node hierarchy to display and then be able to select a node using dot separated node and change the value.

So I could change the `Samples.Dynamics.DN.Range` from `0-36, 37-80` to `0-30, 31-60, 61-90`

```
key = 'Samples.Dynamics.DN.Range'
value = %w(0-30 31-60 61-90)

node_set('Samples.Dynamics.DN.Range', value)
```

I can't work on the later until I figure out how best to display and select the nodes and values.

Comment: I don't quite understand how `Presets` and `Samples` paths are related to `Samples.Dynamics.DN.Range`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648410/3236557) method you can flatten the hash:

```
    def flat_hash(hash, k = [])
      return { k => hash } unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
      hash.inject({}) { |h, v| h.merge! flat_hash(v[-1], k + [v[0]]) }
    end

p flat_hash(json_hash)

#=> {["Samples", "Locations", "Presets"]=>"c:\\Presets\\Inst", ["Samples", "Locations", "Samples"]=>"c:\\Samples\\seperates\\round_robin", ["Samples", "Format", "Type"]=>"AIFF", ["Samples", "Format", "Samplerate"]=>48, ["Samples", "Format", "Bitrate"]=>24, ["Samples", "Groupings", "Type"]=>"dynamic", ["Samples", "Groupings", "Sets", "Keyswitch"]=>"enabled", ["Samples", "Groupings", "Sets", "Mods"]=>"Enabled", ["Samples", "Ranges", "Keys", "LowKey"]=>30, ["Samples", "Ranges", "Keys", "HighKey"]=>80, ["Samples", "Ranges", "Keys", "LowVel"]=>0, ["Samples", "Ranges", "Keys", "MidVel"]=>53, ["Samples", "Ranges", "Keys", "HighVel"]=>127, ["Samples", "Dynamics", "DN", "MultiRange"]=>"enabled", ["Samples", "Dynamics", "DN", "Range"]=>["0-36", "37-80"], ["Modulation", "Pitch"]=>true, ["Modulation", "Range"]=>[], ["Encoded"]=>false, ["test"]=>"test_one"}
```

Using regular expression for valid path `/([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)/` you can filter flatten hash:

```
VALID_PATH_REGEXP = /([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)/

flat_hash(json_hash).each_pair do |k, v|
  puts "#{Array(k).join('.')} => #{v}" if v.to_s =~ VALID_PATH_REGEXP
end

#=> Samples.Locations.Presets => c:\Presets\Inst
#=> Samples.Locations.Samples => c:\Samples\seperates\round_robin
```

---

**Final code:**

```
require 'json'

VALID_PATH_REGEXP = /([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)/

json_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('example.json'))

def flat_hash(hash, k = [])
  return { k => hash } unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.inject({}) { |h, v| h.merge! flat_hash(v[-1], k + [v[0]]) }
end

flat_hash(json_hash).each_pair do |k, v|
  puts "#{Array(k).join('.')} => #{v}" if v.to_s =~ VALID_PATH_REGEXP
end

#=> Samples.Locations.Presets => c:\Presets\Inst
#=> Samples.Locations.Samples => c:\Samples\seperates\round_robin
```

**Update:**

That's probably better to return hash with the results, rather than just printing them:

```
require 'json'

VALID_PATH_REGEXP = /([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)/

json_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('example.json'))

def flat_hash(hash, k = [])
  return { k => hash } unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.inject({}) { |h, v| h.merge! flat_hash(v[-1], k + [v[0]]) }
end

def node_tree(hash)
  flat_hash(hash).map { |k, v| [Array(k).join('.'), v] if v.to_s =~ VALID_PATH_REGEXP }.compact.to_h
end

p node_tree(json_hash)

#=> {"Samples.Locations.Presets"=>"c:\\Presets\\Inst", "Samples.Locations.Samples"=>"c:\\Samples\\seperates\\round_robin"}
```