# Flatten a hash and concatenate the keys

Tags: ruby, hash, flatten

I  have a hash like this:

```
{
 "category" => ["sport", "gaming", "other"],
 "duration" => 312,
 "locations" => { 
    "688CQQ" => {"country" => "France", "state" => "Rhône-Alpes"},
    "aUZCAQ" => {"country" => "France", "state" => "Île de France"}
  }
}
```

I'd like to reduce it to a hash without nesting by flattening a value if the value is a hash. In the final values, I should have only integer, strings or arrays like this:

```
{
  "category" => ["sport", "gaming", "other"],
  "duration" => 312,
  "locations_688CQQ_country" => "France",
  "locations_688CQQ_state" => "Rhône-Alpes",
  "locations_aUZCAQ_country" => "France",
  "locations_aUZCAQ_state" => "Île de France"
}
```

I'd like a function that works with any level of nesting. How can I do that in ruby?

Comment: How deep this hash can be? Is there a limit?

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash

Comment: Your description in the title and in the text is misleading. You are not modifying only the values. You are modifying the keys as well.

Comment: @sawa Indeed. Changed the title

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648515/311744

```
def flat_hash(h, f=nil, g={})
  return g.update({ f => h }) unless h.is_a? Hash
  h.each { |k, r| flat_hash(r, [f,k].compact.join('_'), g) }
  g
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive approach where `h` is your hash.

```
def flat_hash(h)
  h.reduce({}) do |a, (k,v)|
    tmp = v.is_a?(Hash) ? flat_hash(v).map { |k2,v2| ["#{k}_#{k2}",v2]}.to_h : { k => v }
    a.merge(tmp)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34271380/2066657

pardon me while I pile on, here.

```
class ::Hash
  def flat_hash(j='_', h=self, f=nil, g={})
    return g.update({ f => h }) unless h.is_a? Hash
    h.each { |k, r| flat_hash(j, r, [f,k].compact.join(j), g) }
    g
  end
end
```

And now we can do

```
irb> {'foo' =>{'bar'=>{'squee'=>'woot'}}}.flat_hash('')
=> {"foobarsquee"=>"woot"}
```

You owe the Internet Oracle a '!' method.