# How do I flatten a nested hash, recursively, into an array of arrays with a specific format?

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash that looks something like this:

```
{
  'a' => {
    'b' => ['c'],
    'd' => {
      'e' => ['f'],
      'g' => ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    },
    'l' => ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
  },
  'q' => {
    'r' => ['s']
  }
}
```

The hash can have even more nesting, but the values of the last level are always arrays.

I would like to "flatten" the hash into a format where I get a an array of arrays representing all keys and values that makes up an entire "path/branch" of the nested hash all they way from lowest level value to the top of the hash. So kind of like traversing up through the "tree" starting from the bottom while collecting keys and values on the way.

The output of that for the particular hash should be:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  ['a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
  ['a', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'],
  ['q', 'r', 's']
]
```

I tried many different things, but nothing worked so far. Again keep in mind that more levels than these might occur, so the solution has to be generic.

**Note:** the order of the arrays and the order of the elements in them is not important.

I did the following, but it's not really working:

```
tree_def = {
  'a' => {
    'b' => ['c'],
    'd' => {
      'e' => ['f'],
      'g' => ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    },
    'l' => ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
  },
  'q' => {
    'r' => ['s']
  }
}
branches = [[]]

collect_branches = lambda do |tree, current_branch|
  tree.each do |key, hash_or_values|
    current_branch.push(key)
    if hash_or_values.kind_of?(Hash)
      collect_branches.call(hash_or_values, branches.last)
    else # Reached lowest level in dependency tree (which is always an array)
      # Add a new branch
      branches.push(current_branch.clone)
      current_branch.push(*hash_or_values)
      current_branch = branches.last
    end
  end
end

collect_branches.call(tree_def, branches[0])

branches #=> wrong result
```

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward. Descend into hashes recursively, taking note of keys you visited in this branch. When you see an array, no need to recurse further. Append it to the list of keys and return.

Comment: "So kind of like traversing up through the 'tree'" - yes. I'd say, this is _exactly_ like traversing a tree. Only not sure why you see this as "starting from the bottom".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That was just to make it more "clear" what the output was representing, there are 5 "final" values which will eventually give 5 branches. It's good advice you give, however I still struggle to figure the code on how to keep track of which "branch" to add what values to while traversing recursively...

Comment: Tracking is easy, just pass the temp state down to recursive calls in arguments.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23861946/10522579) can be best solution provided by @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments:

> Looks pretty straightforward. Descend into hashes recursively, taking note of keys you visited in this branch. When you see an array, no need to recurse further. Append it to the list of keys and return
>
> Tracking is easy, just pass the temp state down to recursive calls in arguments.

I meant something like this:

```
def tree_flatten(tree, path = [], &block)
  case tree
  when Array
    block.call(path + tree)
  else
    tree.each do |key, sub_tree|
      tree_flatten(sub_tree, path + [key], &block)
    end
  end
end

tree_flatten(tree_def) do |path|
  p path
end
```

This code simply prints each flattened path as it gets one, but you can store it in an array too. Or even modify `tree_flatten` to return you a ready array, instead of yielding elements one by one.

Comment: Great answer, I see!

Comment: If the OP is happy with this then great, but `tree_flatten` does not return desired data structure (array).

Comment: @ArtuX Yes, this is explicitly mentioned. Plus, it'd be a good exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```rb
def flat_hash(h)
  return [h] unless h.kind_of?(Hash)
  h.map{|k,v| flat_hash(v).map{|e| e.unshift(k)} }.flatten(1)
end

input = {
  'a' => {
    'b' => ['c'],
    'd' => {
      'e' => ['f'],
      'g' => ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    },
    'l' => ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
  },
  'q' => {
    'r' => ['s']
  }
}

p flat_hash(input)
```

The output will be:

```
[
  ["a", "b", "c"], 
  ["a", "d", "e", "f"], 
  ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"], 
  ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], 
  ["q", "r", "s"]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

This of course calls for a recursive solution. The following method does not mutate the original hash.

**Code**

```
def recurse(h)
  h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),arr|
    v.is_a?(Hash) ? recurse(v).each { |a| arr << [k,*a] } : arr << [k,*v]
  end 
end
```

**Example**

```
h = { 'a'=>{ 'b'=>['c'],
             'd'=>{ 'e'=>['f'], 'g' => ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'] },
             'l' => ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'] },
      'q'=>{ 'r'=>['s'] } }
```

```
recurse h
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"],
  #    ["a", "d", "e", "f"],
  #    ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
  #    ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"],
  #    ["q", "r", "s"]]
```

**Explanation**

The operations performed by recursive methods are always difficult to explain. In my experience the best way is to salt the code with puts statements. However, that in itself is not enough because when viewing output it is difficult to keep track of the level of recursion at which particular results are obtained and either passed to itself or returned to a version of itself. The solution to that is to indent and un-indent results, which is what I've done below. Note the way I've structured the code and the few helper methods I use are fairly general-purpose, so this approach can be adapted to examine the operations performed by other recursive methods.

```
INDENT = 8
def indent; @col += INDENT; end
def undent; @col -= INDENT; end
def pu(s); print " "*@col; puts s; end
def puhline; pu('-'*(70-@col)); end 
@col = -INDENT
```

```
def recurse(h)
  begin
    indent
    puhline
    pu "passed h = #{h}"
    h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),arr|
      pu "  k = #{k}, v=#{v}, arr=#{arr}"
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        pu "  calling recurse(#{v})"
        ar = recurse(v)
        pu "  return value=#{ar}"
        pu "  calculating recurse(v).each { |a| arr << [k,*a] }"
        ar.each do |a|
          pu "    a=#{a}"
          pu "    [k, *a] = #{[k,*a]}"
          arr << [k,*a]
        end
      else
        pu "  arr << #{[k,*v]}"
        arr << [k,*v]
      end
      pu "arr = #{arr}"
    end.tap { |a| pu "returning=#{a}" }
  ensure
    puhline
    undent
  end
end
```

```
recurse h
----------------------------------------------------------------------
passed h = {"a"=>{"b"=>["c"], "d"=>{"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]},
            "l"=>["m", "n", "o", "p"]}, "q"=>{"r"=>["s"]}}
  k = a, v={"b"=>["c"], "d"=>{"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]},
            "l"=>["m", "n", "o", "p"]}, arr=[]
  calling recurse({"b"=>["c"], "d"=>{"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]},
                   "l"=>["m", "n", "o", "p"]})
        --------------------------------------------------------------
        passed h = {"b"=>["c"], "d"=>{"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]},
                    "l"=>["m", "n", "o", "p"]}
          k = b, v=["c"], arr=[]
          arr << ["b", "c"]
        arr = [["b", "c"]]
          k = d, v={"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]}, arr=[["b", "c"]]
          calling recurse({"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]})
                ------------------------------------------------------
                passed h = {"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]}
                  k = e, v=["f"], arr=[]
                  arr << ["e", "f"]
                arr = [["e", "f"]]
                  k = g, v=["h", "i", "j", "k"], arr=[["e", "f"]]
                  arr << ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
                arr = [["e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
                returning=[["e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
                ------------------------------------------------------
```

```
          return value=[["e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
          calculating recurse(v).each { |a| arr << [k,*a] }
            a=["e", "f"]
            [k, *a] = ["d", "e", "f"]
            a=["g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
            [k, *a] = ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
        arr = [["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
          k = l, v=["m", "n", "o", "p"],
            arr=[["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
          arr << ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]
        arr = [["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
               ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]]
        returning=[["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
                   ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]]
        --------------------------------------------------------------
  return value=[["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
                ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]]
  calculating recurse(v).each { |a| arr << [k,*a] }
    a=["b", "c"]
    [k, *a] = ["a", "b", "c"]
    a=["d", "e", "f"]
    [k, *a] = ["a", "d", "e", "f"]
    a=["d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
    [k, *a] = ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
    a=["l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]
    [k, *a] = ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]
arr = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
       ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]]
  k = q, v={"r"=>["s"]}, arr=[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"],
    ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"], ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]]
  calling recurse({"r"=>["s"]})
        --------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
        passed h = {"r"=>["s"]}
          k = r, v=["s"], arr=[]
          arr << ["r", "s"]
        arr = [["r", "s"]]
        returning=[["r", "s"]]
        --------------------------------------------------------------
  return value=[["r", "s"]]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  calculating recurse(v).each { |a| arr << [k,*a] }
    a=["r", "s"]
    [k, *a] = ["q", "r", "s"]
arr = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
       ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s"]]
returning=[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
           ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s"]]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
  #    ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

See following which will keep calling recursively till it reaches to array values.

This recursion call will go with multiple branches and `op` should be individual copy for each branch so I used string which is always created as a new object here otherwise array will be like going with **call by reference**

```
hash = {"a"=>{"b"=>["c"], "d"=>{"e"=>["f"], "g"=>["h", "i", "j", "k"]}, "l"=>["m", "n", "o", "p"]}, "q"=>{"r"=>["s"]}}

@output = []

def nested_array(h, op='')
  h.map do |k,v|
    if Hash === v
      nested_array(v, op+k)
    else
      @output << (op+k+v.join).chars
    end
  end
end

nested_array(hash)
```

`@output` will be your desired array.

```
[
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["a", "d", "e", "f"],
  ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"], 
  ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], 
  ["q", "r", "s"]
]
```

**update:** key values pair can be more than single character so following approach for `nested_array` may work better.

```
def nested_array(h, op=[])
  h.map do |k,v|
    if Hash === v
      nested_array(v, Array.new(op) << k)
    else
      @output << ((Array.new(op) << k) + v)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good start, but don't roundtrip via a string. Real data won't have single-letter keys/values.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree, I just did above as per user case. I added why I round-trip via string instead of array. This satisfy user scenario but better approach is needed for sure.

Comment: Your comment about references does not really make sense, I'm afraid. If you want to create a new array, you can. If you want to pass a string by reference, you can too, just as easily.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, got it, I updated answer, but I liked your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This will return an Array with all the paths.

```
def paths(element, path = [], accu = [])
  case element
  when Hash
    element.each do |key, value|
      paths(value, path + [key], accu)
    end
  when Array
    accu << (path + element)
  end
  accu
end
```

For nicer printing you can do

```
paths(tree_def).map { |path| path.join(".") }
```

Answer (score 0):

> All the solutions here are recursive, below is a non-recursive
>   solution.

```
def flatten(input)
  sol = []
  while(input.length > 0)
    unprocessed_input = []
    input.each do |l, r|
      if r.is_a?(Array)
        sol << l + r
      else
        r.each { |k, v| unprocessed_input << [l + [k], v] }
      end
    end
    input = unprocessed_input
  end
  return sol
end
flatten([[[], h]])
```

Code Explanation:

- Hash in array form is [[k1, v1], [k2, v2]].
- When input_hash is presented in the above form, [[], { a: {..} }], partial_solutions of this form, [ [a], {..} ], can be generated. Index '0' holds the partial solution and Index '1' holds the yet to be processed input.
- As this format is easy to map partial_solution with unprocessed input and accumulate unprocessed input, converting input_hash to this format result in, [[[], input_hash]]

Solution:

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"], ["q", "r", "s"], ["a", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "d", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution similar to this. In my use-case, I wanted any array to be permutated over with the previous "path" up to that point. I wanted to write somewhat concise structures that could represent "paths" (not necessarily file paths, but perhaps message routing paths) and be expanded when needed. A simple example of that would be

```
hash2 = {"a"=>{"b"=>["c", "d"]}}
expand_structure(hash2)
# [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"]]
```

So the solution I came up with is below.

```
def expand_structure(o, path=[])
  case o
  when Hash
    o.inject([]) do |collector, (k, v)|
      collector += expand_structure(v, path + [k])
    end
  when Array
    o.map { |e| expand_structure(e, path) }
  else # unstructured "value"
    path + [o]
  end
end
```

That being said, if you want to keep your arrays flat versus permutating over them, you could modify the above to not recurse further and simply return the array appended to the path.

```
def expand_structure2(o, path=[])
  case o
  when Hash
    o.inject([]) do |collector, (k, v)|
      collector += expand_structure2(v, path + [k])
    end
  when Array
    [path + o]
  else # unstructured "value"
    path + [o]
  end
end

# Using your original case:
h = {
  'a' => {
    'b' => ['c'],
    'd' => {
      'e' => ['f'],
      'g' => ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    },
    'l' => ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
  },
  'q' => {
    'r' => ['s']
  }
}

expand_structure2(h) == [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  ['a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'],
  ['a', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'],
  ['q', 'r', 's']
]

# => true
```

Note: I'm undecided on a method name; obviously at the end of the day that's up to the programmer, but it's an interesting problem where in some sense the structure is expanding, and in others it's flattening.