# How to instantiate a multilevel hash with an arbitrary depth

Tags: ruby

I want to create a hash from the result of a database query such that its keys are the column values except the last one, and the value are the last column value (or a default value). For example, if I have rows:

```
1 2 3 1
1 2 4 9
1 3 2 nil
```

and a default value of `111`, I should get:

```
{
  1 => 
       {
          2 => { 3 => 1, 4 => 9},
          3 => { 2 => 111}
       }
}
```

I want to make the method generic enough to handle an arbitrary number of columns, so the signature could be:

```
to_lookup(rows, default_value, value_column, *columns)
```

How would I go about that?

**Update**: forgot a comma in the output.

Comment: What exactly is the input?

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404769.

Comment: The input is the result of a database query, but you can think of it as an array of arrays where each row is an array. If you copy/paste the expected output into an irb session I believe it won't throw an exception.

Comment: Interesting question, but you should edit to provide a second example to show whether rows are to be grouped or consecutive rows are to be grouped. You could do that with `arr = [[1, 1, 2, 1], [3]]`, for example.

Comment: In future, when you give an example, always have valid Ruby objects as inputs and assign each to a variable (e.g., `arr = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 4, 9], [1, 3, 2, nil]]`. You may have thought displaying a picture of the array made it clearer, but we cannot cut and paste that. Of course you can always write it as I have but with each element ("row") of `arr` on a separate line. By assigning objects to variables readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them. Lastly, remove extraneous bits, here replacing `nil` with a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified things by removing the ability to pass a default,
I also simplified the signature method to have only one parameter.

```
RSpec.describe "#to_lookup" do

  def to_lookup(rows)
    return rows.first.first if rows.flatten.size == 1
    h = {}
    rows.group_by { |e| e.first }.each_entry do |k, v|
      v.each &:shift
     h[k] = to_lookup(v)
    end
    h
  end


  let :input do
    [
      [1, 2, 3, 1],
      [1, 2, 4, 9],
      [1, 3, 2, 111],
    ]
  end

  let :output do
    {
      1 => {
          2 => {3 => 1, 4 => 9},
          3 => {2 => 111}
      }
    }
  end

  it { expect(to_lookup(input)).to eq(output) }

end
```

BTW I wonder what output do you want for following input:

```
 1 2 3 1
 1 2 3 2
```

EDIT: working code snippet: http://rubysandbox.com/#/snippet/566aefa80195f1000c000000

Comment: You're right. I expect it should be `group_by`, not `slice_when` or `chunk`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You can sort the array first and `slice_when` will do the trick either.

Comment: Readers: cthulhu's comment is a general one, relating `Enumerable#group_by` to `Enumerable#slice_when` (or `Enumerable#chunk`).

Answer (score 3):

[Edit: after reading @cthulhu's answer, I think I may have misinterpreted the question. I assumed that consecutive rows were to be grouped, rather than all rows to be grouped. I will leave my answer for the former interpretation.]

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
def hashify(arr)
  return arr.first.first if arr.first.size == 1  
  arr.slice_when { |f,s| f.first != s.first }.
      each_with_object({}) do |a,h|
        key, *rest = a.transpose
        h[key.first] = hashify(rest.transpose)
      end
end

hashify [[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 4, 9], [1, 3, 2, nil]]
  #=> {1=>{2=>{3=>1, 4=>9}, 3=>{2=>nil}}} 

hashify [[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 4, 9], [2, 3, 2, nil]]
  #=> {1=>{2=>{3=>1, 4=>9}}, 2=>{3=>{2=>nil}}}
```

Replacing `nil` with the default can be done before or after the construction of the hash.

[Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) was bestowed upon us in v2.2. For earlier versions, you could replace:

```
arr.slice_when { |f,s| f.first != s.first }
```

with

```
arr.chunk { |row| row.first }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: Soon, you will be able to use `chunk_while` instead of `slice_when` so that you don't have to negate the block.

Comment: @sawa, did you mean `slice_while`? I've been meaning to suggest that [Array#difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements) be added as a core method. Where would I do that?