# Generate a tree from string split

Tags: ruby, dynamic, data-structures, tree, dynamic-programming

I have an array of strings

```
["ana_ola_una",
"ana_ola_ina",
"ana_asta",
"ana_ena_ola", 
"ana_ena_cala",
"ana_ena_cina",
"ana_ena_cina_ula"]
```

I need to reformat it as a hash of hashes of hashes of ... to make it a tree. The expected result would be:

```
{ana: 
    {
     ola: {
           una: {},
           ina: {}
          }, 
     asta: {},
     ena: {
           ola: {}, 
           cala:{},
           cina: 
                {
                ula: {}
                }
           }
     }
}
```

EDIT:

I edit this issue because I have a related question, finally I want it in a JSON with this format. How could I do:

```
var tree = [
        {
            text: "Parent 1",
            nodes: [
                {
                    text: "Child 1",
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 1"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Child 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 2"
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 3"
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 4"
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 5"
        }
    ];
```

Comment: This is not a list of strings. This is an array of literals.

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404769.

Comment: @mudasobwa Sorry for the bad format, but I wasn't closed to a strict Ruby answer, I just wanted to translate my idea as generic. I was asking for help for the algorith not for the language.

Comment: SO wants you to ask only one question at a time. You should post the "related question" as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = %w|ana_ola_una
  ana_ola_ina
  ana_asta
  ana_ena_ola
  ana_ena_cala
  ana_ena_cina
  ana_ena_cina_ula|

result = arr.each_with_object({}) do |s, memo|
  s.split('_').inject(memo) do |deep, k|
    deep[k.to_sym] ||= {}
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's all I need.

Answer (score 2):

mudasobwa's answer is good, but if you're using Ruby 2.3+ here's a slightly more concise alternative:

```
arr = [
  "ana_ola_una",
  "ana_ola_ina",
  "ana_asta",
  "ana_ena_ola", 
  "ana_ena_cala",
  "ana_ena_cina",
  "ana_ena_cina_ula"
]

tree = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
arr.each {|str| tree.dig(*str.split(?_).map(&:to_sym)) }

p tree
# => { ana:
#      { ola:
#        { una: {},
#          ina: {}
#        },
#        asta: {},
#        ena:
#        { ola: {},
#          cala: {},
#          cina: { ula: {} }
#        }
#      }
#    }
```